# How do i make my Nav Display This popup using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup

i need to pop up to pop when ever i click on `Pop Up` on my `navbar` 
I have tried all i could, still not working.
HELP, Thank You

**my Navbar Component**

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">

          <li className="nav-item active">
            <a className="nav-link" href="">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>

          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">
              Pop Up
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

**My Pop up Component** 
i added some conditions to it already

```
import React from "react";

const PopUp = (props) => {
  return props.trigger ? (
    <div className="popup" style={popUpStyle} id="popup">
      <h1>Pop Up</h1>
      <p>
        This is a pop up. <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. A fuga eum sapiente ratione tempora veniam odio
        corrupti, praesentium natus optio consequatur dignissimos deserunt
        voluptas nihil quam amet distinctio maiores voluptatibus.
      </p>
      <p className="closepop">Close</p>
    </div>
  ) : (
    ""
  );
};
export default PopUp;
```

**My App**

```
import "./App.css";
import PopUp from "./components/popup";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopUp] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PopUp trigger={buttonPopup} />;
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Any help will be Appreciated. Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [Lifting States Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to implement this.
You didn't use your Navbar component, so I am assuming it will be called in **App.jsx.**
Implemented that in your code:

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [buttonPopup, setButtonPopUp] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar setButtonPopUp={setButtonPopUp} buttonPopup={buttonPopup} />
      <PopUp trigger={buttonPopup} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

NavBar.js

```
function Navbar(props) {
  const { setButtonPopUp, buttonPopup }= props;
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={() => setButtonPopUp(!buttonPopup)}>
              Pop Up
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

Hope I solved your query!!!

Comment: thankn you for the helping hand, But its says ```'props' is not defined on the navbar component```. is there another approach for this, please?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: yeah thanks, it worked, i usethe same approach for the close buttton of my pop up. thanks

Comment: Please accept and upvote an answer.l, if the solution works for you.